# microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning - case-insensitive URI endpoints

Tags: c#, odata, versioning, case-sensitive

I have created OData Web Service using Microsoft.AspNet.OData(7.2.0) with .NET Framework 4.7.

My OData Web Service was working correctly, the URI endpoints were case-insensitive, like:

- http://${host}/Value(256)/ was working correctly (using ValueController)
- http://${host}/value(256)/ was working correctly (using the same ValueController)

Later, I enhanced my OData Web Service with versioning using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Versioning(4.0.0)

My OData Web Service works correctly only for the case-sensitive URI endpoints now, like:

- http://${host}/Value(256)?api-version=1.0 is working correctly (using ValueController)
- http://${host}/value(256)?api-version=1.0 is not working anymore and returns 404 - File or directory not found.

Please how to set up the URI Endpoints to be case-insensitive after the Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Versioning(4.0.0) came into the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you the exact reason why adding versioning via Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Versioning fails, but I can provide a workaround.  See the CoinfigureContainer method below.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.AddApiVersioning(setup =>
        {
            setup.DefaultApiVersion = new Microsoft.Web.Http.ApiVersion(1, 0);
            setup.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
        });

        VersionedODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new VersionedODataModelBuilder(config)
        {
            ModelBuilderFactory = () => new ODataConventionModelBuilder().EnableLowerCamelCase(),
            ModelConfigurations = { new xxxxConfiguration(), new yyyyConfiguration() }
        };

        config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);

        config.MapVersionedODataRoutes("ODataRoute", "odata/v{apiVersion}", modelBuilder.GetEdmModels(), ConfigureContainer);

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }

    static void ConfigureContainer(IContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.AddService<ODataUriResolver>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => new UnqualifiedCallAndEnumPrefixFreeResolver() { EnableCaseInsensitive = true });
    }
}
```

My *speculation* is that the addition of the versioning library somehow replaces the ODataUriResolver that has the EnablesCaseInsensitive = true property set.  This code "resets" the ODataUriResolver.

FYI - I stumbled across the code that this is based on at https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/master/samples/webapi/BasicODataWebApiSample/Startup.cs.